# How to insert * AND + OPERATORS between a given set of integers so that the expression evaluates to the max possible value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, operator-precedence

if Set is [3,4,5,6,-2]
it should give 3*4*5*6+-2 and also note that * gets precedence over + while evaluating

Numbers can be repeated, duplicates are allowed

Saw this in a blog, but could not come up with an answer other than doing a brute force exhaustive search

Comment: What makes you think there's a better solution than exhaustive search?

Comment: If there is a better algorithm, math.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask about it. It's not really a programming problem.

Comment: roger that, will try posting there

Comment: @Barmar Exhaustive search is O(2^n) which can get intractable really soon

Comment: @mck What makes you think I don't know that? What makes you think there's an algorithm that isn't exponential?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: there are far less people who know abt math.stackexchange, I for one heard that name first time here, now

Comment: As a mathematician and computer scientist, I would consider this more a problem of algorithm design than a mathematical problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513130/generate-max-value-expression

Comment: @Barmar,@frank, this might well have a DP solution, categorizing this as off-topic is not the correct way to go

Comment: the dumbing down of stackoverflow continues.  questions about possible dp solutions are now "maths"

Comment: @JATMON come to [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).